# These pictures are out of order, but how should they be?

Tags: sports

These 4 **sporty** images are out of order.  Can you figure out what they have in common and how they should be ordered?

[image: 4 Images]

Comment: what car is that?

Comment: @lois6b I think it's a *Ford Freestyle FX 2004*

Comment: There are like million order for them, no one can enter your mind and tell the order you consider. Unless there is something I can't notice in your question.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat There's more like 24 different orders for 4 images.  But yes they do have something which tie them to a specific order.  PROTIP: check the tags.

Comment: Crap!  Why is this on hold?  It's not speculative at all, if you can figure it out.  I think the hold-fiends just get frustrated and express it with unwarranted holds.

Comment: How is one expected to know the *model* of that car?

Comment: I (1) spy (3) with my bird eye (4) something black (2) was the first thing that came to mind :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's

> 3, 1, 4, 2

since

> it represents the order of strokes in a swimming medley:
>  3: Butterfly (butterfly knife)
>  1: Backstroke (backpack)
>  4: Breaststroke (orange-breasted falcon, perhaps)
>  2: Freestyle (Ford Freestyle FX 2004)

Answer (score 8):

Probably incorrect:

> Bird, backpack, man with knife,  car

This is a stretch and incomplete but:

> They could refer to the order of strokes in a swimming medley.  Bird's fly so that represents the butterfly stroke.  Backpack represents the backstroke. The man with the knife would have to represent the breaststroke somehow (not sure how).  The car is a freestyle and represents the freestyle.

Comment: You are on to something with the reasoning, but the order is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several ways to line them up:

> 1 3 2 4 speed
>  4 1 3 2 size
>  1 3 4 2 price (3 means video game)
>  other ways I could think of would be alphabet, rarity, color,... and so on

Since there is a tag I go for

> <strike>1 3 2 4 speed, from slowest to fastest. Assuming the OP got hold of the well-known fact a falcon is pretty fast and decided to make a riddle about it</strike>
> To name one more it could also be the time a kind of sport related to the object was invented.
>  1 4 2 3

and so on...

Comment: None of these are correct.  Note the [sports] tag